# How can to ignore a Nan in a .csv file in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, missing-data

I have a problem while reading the columns of my .csv file. I have this code:

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('D:/CTU/ateroskleroza/development/results_output6.csv')
print(dataset.head())


X = dataset.iloc[:, 2:16].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values


# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25)

classifier = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), SVC(gamma='auto'))
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)
# Generating accuracy, precision, recall and f1-score

target_names = ['Progressive','Stable']
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

And the .csv looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Depending of the name of the pictures they have some columns, some other are with Nan. The problem is that when I try to execute this code I have this error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

So how can I ignore the Nan and only use the numbers? (I don't want to remove the empty columns, just ignore the Nan while executing).

Comment: you need to come with a strategy for it, it can be `df.fillna(0.0)` or so.

Comment: @simpleApp But then my results are going to change, right? Because I'm putting a value  to a Nan and if I train with this results they are going to affect to the final result

Comment: yes or no. whenever there is nan value, there would need some plan of attack. either you drop the feature if it's too sparse or replace it with some value.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer based on personal experience. If you want a more detailed answer, consider updating your post with a dataset we can use, state what the model is supposed to predict and describe the features.

@simpleApp suggested replacing null values with zero prior to scaling the data and fitting the model. In the comments, you seem concerned about the effects of imputing null values on the final model.

When dealing with missing data, you have to weigh the pros and cons of imputing values. If you decide to ignore the observations with null values (either by dropping columns or whole observations), you could be missing out on some really important information and you won't be able to make predictions on new observations unless their data is completely full. Likewise, if you carelessly impute null values with some random  value, you could introduce a bias to the model.

If you impute values correctly, your model will be able to handle missing data without compromising much of its accuracy. Sadly though, imputing values is more of an art than a hard science.

I have no idea what your data means, but think of age as an independent variable to predict risk of heart disease. Ask yourself: if a value is missing, am I better off ignoring the observation, or can I fill the void with a value that, on average, should not be too far away from the real unobserved age of the patient?

If you decide you fill the missing information with some value, I would suggest four really simple methods:

```py
# Fill with minimum value
df = df.fillna(df.mean(), axis=1)

# Fill with median value
df = df.fillna(df.median(), axis=0)

# Fill with mean value
df = df.fillna(df.mean(), axis=0)

# Fill with maximum value
df = df.fillna(df.max(), axis=0)
```

Your next step should be to score the resulting models and choose the one that generalizes best on unseen data.

Among other common imputation techniques, you can fill null values with zero (`df.fillna(0)`), with the most frequent value (check [SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html)) or with more complex imputing techniques, such as [nearest neighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#nearest-neighbors-imputation).

In the end, you will find out if imputing nulls was the right thing to do when you test your model's performance on unseen data.

As a general rule of thumb, you should consider dropping all columns that have more than 20% of their values missing.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate your answer. The point is that I don't want to fill the NaN's, I just want to ignore them. Is it impossible?

Comment: No, that is not possible, especially with an SVC model. Either you i) drop rows with NaNs, ii) drop those columns or iii) fill in the null values. If you think about it, not passing a value is information in itself. So you can never truly "ignore" NaNs. We just fill them up in order to avoid data type collisions.